How can we show that $((\vec v · \vec r) \vec r )'$ corresponds to Coriolis force?
We have:

Position as  $\vec r$
Velocity as $\vec v=(\vec r)'$
Acceleration as $\vec a=(\vec v)'$
Angular velocity as $\vec \omega = \frac{\vec r × \vec v}{r^2}$
Angular acceleration as $\vec \alpha = (\vec \omega)'$

Cross multiplying $\vec r$ and then differentiating with respect to time on both sides in (3), we get,
$\vec v - (\vec v · \hat r)\hat r =\vec \omega × \vec r$
$ \Rightarrow \vec v= (\vec v· \hat r)\hat r + \vec \omega × \vec r $
$\Rightarrow \vec a = ((\vec v·\hat r)\hat r)' + \vec \omega × \vec v + \vec \alpha × \vec r$
Now, in rotational frame of reference, $\vec \omega × \vec v$ corresponds to centrifugal force, $\vec \alpha × \vec r $ corresponds to Euler force. So, $((\vec v · \hat r)\hat r)'$ should correspond to Coriolis force and we should get $((\vec v · \hat r)\hat r)'$ equal to $ 2 \vec \omega × (\vec v · \hat r)\hat r$. Now, expanding first term we get,
$((\vec v · \hat r)\hat r)'$
$=(\frac{(\vec v · \vec r)\vec r}{r^2})'$
$=\frac{((\vec v · \vec r)\vec r)' r^2 - 2(\vec v · \vec r)(\vec v · \vec r) \vec r}{r^4}$
$=\frac{((\vec v · \vec r)\vec v + (\vec v ·\vec r)' \vec r ) }{r^2} - \frac{2(\vec v · \vec r)^2 \vec r}{r^4}$
$=\frac{((\vec v · \vec r)\vec v + (\vec a ·\vec r)\vec r + v^2 \vec r) }{r^2} - \frac{2(\vec v · \vec r)^2 \vec r}{r^4}$
And, expanding second term we get,
$2\vec \omega × (\vec v · \hat r)\hat r$
$=\frac{2(\vec r × \vec v ) × (\vec v · \vec r )\vec r}{r^2 × r^2}$
$=\frac {2(\vec v · \vec r)((\vec r × \vec v ) × \vec r)}{r^4}$
$=\frac {-2(\vec v · \vec r)((\vec r × (\vec r  × \vec v)}{r^4}$
$=\frac {-2(\vec v · \vec r)((\vec r· \vec v)\vec r -   r^{2} \vec v)}{r^4}$
$= \frac {2(\vec v · \vec r)\vec v}{r^2}   
- \frac{2(\vec v· \vec r)^2 \vec r}{r^4}$
Clearly, we are not getting them same. So, is the assumption that $((\vec v · \hat r)\hat r)'$ corresponds to Coriolis force incorrect? If not then how can we show that both the terms are equal?

for $~\vec r=r,\left[ \begin {array}{c} \cos \left( \varphi (t) \right)
\ \sin \left( \varphi(t)  \right) \end {array}
\right]
~$ you obtain $~\vec v\cdot {\hat{r}}= 0~$

@Eli That's true, but in such a case Coriolis force won't even appear.

why not ? $~\vec v~$ is still equal $~\vec\omega\times \vec r~$

Related : Velocity in a turning reference frame.

@Eli if $\vec v · \hat r = 0 $ then $\vec a = \vec \omega × \vec r + \vec \alpha × \vec r$, so if we observe a particle of mass $m$ with our frame of reference having acceleration $a$, we will see pseudo force $-ma$ on it. Which means we will only see centrifugal force and euler force.

@Navneet $(\vec v· \hat r)\hat r=\frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm dt}\hat r$. Basically, you are writing the velocity as a sum of tangential and normal velocity, i.e., $\vec v= (\vec v· \hat r)\hat r + \vec \omega × \vec r=\frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm dt}\hat r+\vec \omega × \vec r$. Also, $\frac{\mathrm d\vec r}{\mathrm dt}=\frac{\mathrm d r\hat r}{\mathrm dt}=\frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm dt}\cdot\hat r+r\frac{\mathrm d\hat r}{\mathrm dt}$.

To derive those accelerations, you must consider additional terms due to rotation. $$\dfrac{\mathrm d\vec r}{\mathrm dt}=\left[\dfrac{\mathrm d\vec r}{\mathrm dt}\right]_\text{frame}+\vec\omega\times\vec r$$

$~((\vec v·\hat r)\hat r)' + \vec \omega × \vec v~$ is equal to $~2,\vec \omega\times \vec v+\vec\omega\times,(\omega\times\vec r)~$
